# Mockito.`when`(....) is calling actual implementation.?

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, mockito

I have one weird issue that my mock is calling actual implementation of code. I am testing my controller class which have a simple POST end point. Here i would like explain in step. Please note that i am using Kotlin and Spring boot (spring 5). Here is my controller class

```
@RestController
class MyController(val delegate: DelegateTask) { 

    @PostMapping(value = ["/x1/myprofile/xyzz"], produces = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun doSomething(@RequestHeader("id",  required = false) id: String?,
                    @RequestHeader("oid", required = false) oid: String?,
                    @RequestHeader("username") userName: String,
                    @RequestHeader("cache-access", required = false) cacheAccess: String?,
                    @RequestBody(required = true) reqPayload: RequestPayload,
                    request: HttpServletRequest): ResponseObject {
        val result = delegate.myjob(id, oid, userName, cacheAccess, reqPayload)
        return result.responseObject
    }
}
```

Now come to my test case

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class MyControllerTest {

var delegator:DelegateTask = mock()

@Test
    fun testMyController(){
         Mockito.`when`(delegator.myjob("mockid","mockoid","mockUName",
                "cache",mockRequestPayload())).thenReturn(getResourceAsMockResponse().result.responseObj)

 var result = mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/x1/myprofile/xyzz")
                    .header("id", "mockid")
                    .header("oid", "mockoid")
                    .header("username", "someuser")
                    .contentType("application/json")
                    .content(Gson().toJson(mockReqData())))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk)
            .andExpect { }
            .andReturn()

}
```

When i am calling

> Mockito.`when`(delegator.myjob(.....))

It's calling actual method even it should mock this method job, I am not sure why this is calling actual implementation of method.

Comment: Does `when` also specify the parameter values for which the method will be mocked? I don't know about `cacheAccess` or `reqPayload` but `username` won't match.

Comment: Can you please explain bit more..?

Comment: I'm asking if Mockito's `when` checks for parameter matching. The parameters you call it with don't match your `when` declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But as you said this not the CASE. Because whatever will pass in "when" it will mock accordingly and I have double checked it all parameter r correct.

Comment: I don't know what you just said. Normally when you specify a `when` clause you pass in either (a) parameter values to match, or something like `anyString()`. In your `when` clause you specify `"mockUName"` as the third parameter, in your post you pass in `"someuser"`. Those aren't equal strings, your `when` clause won't match.

Comment: I have tried with Mockito.anyString()..but no luck... :(

Comment: Maybe you should check the parameters in the controller.